# Camera obscura chemical inquiry

Tags: organic-chemistry

I’d like to make a rather large scale camera obscura and use the light reflected inside of it to recreate the first process for a permanent image so I need a sheet metal as well as a chemical (the recommended is bitumen of judea), to expose the sheet metal to create a heliograph image, it is then said that Niepsce used oil of lavender to wipe off unexposed bitumen(I’m assuming it’s a solvent so I’d also need one to pair with whatever chemical you’d recommend for exposing). The end result is going to be rather large scale so I’d like to use a lens that won’t let in as much light as a glass lens because I believe that this will cause the image to be overexposed I was curious as to what chemical I should use to apply to the metal sheet, and what type of metal to use to get the best result that will be the most light sensitive and result in a clear final product. If this doesn’t make sense I apologize and I’d be glad to try and make as much sense of it as possible, any help is good help thank you![image]

Comment: Glass lens?! Camera Obscura a.k.a. pinhole camera doesn't use any lenses - just a tiny hole in the side opposite to the screen/film. This also causes very little light to enter, making for its primary drawbacks: long exposure time, need for bright scenes.

Comment: @SF. As addendum: The lens in the camera obscura is the aperture; the pinhole. If the aperture vs image size and depth of field necessary is adjusted correctly, there is no need for a focusing lens. All incoming light arrives (nearly) perpendicular to the image plane.

Comment: I believe the original photo plate was made of silver. However, having seen the result with my own eyes (it's currently kept in a museum a few miles from my place) I'm not sure you'd want to replicate his procedure exactly. Granted the plate has aged quite a bit, but it takes most people a minute or two to be able to see anything at all.